# Config error: The requested service could not be activated

Tags: 2010, web-part, iis, virtual-directory

I am trying to deploy and use a web part developed in SP2010 that requires connecting from a SP2010 server to a SQL server. I get the following error (greatly abbreviated):

```
The requested service, '[blocked; this is not what it says on the error]//_vti_bin/PSI/Lists.svc', could not be activated. See the server's diagnostic trace logs for more information.
```

I saw nothing in the logs from `".../14/logs/"` that could tell me anything. When I check the `Lists.svc` at that location in IIS, it brings up an error page, noting that the config file could not be accessed due to not having permission.

In fact, when I added the `"_vti_bin"` folder as a Virtual Directory, it gave me the warning that it wasn't sure if the account I'm using even has access to that path.

So what are the errors, and how do I fix the configuration errors?